# 2 problems with testing asp.net membership provider

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-membership

I have created a unit test to search for users by name. I have 2 problems I cant figure out.

1. `Assert.IsTrue(coll.Count == 2)` doesnt count the users as it should. There should be 2 users and it only counts 1.
2. `Assert.IsTrue(usernames.Contains("testUser"));` doesn't find the partial username string as it should. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestFindUsersByName()
{
    //set test to crate user 
    AsaMembershipProvider prov = this.GetMembershipProvider();
    MembershipCreateStatus status;
    //creates users
    MembershipUser user1 = prov.CreateUser("testUser1", "12345", "test.User1@abc.com", "", "", true, null, out status);
    MembershipUser user2 = prov.CreateUser("testUser2", "12345", "test.User2@abc.com", "", "", true, null, out status);

    //gets users
    user1 = prov.GetUser("testUser1", false); //not checking if user is online. Argument should be false. Not yet implemented 
    user2 = prov.GetUser("testUser2", false);

    int pageSize = 5;
    int pageIndex = 0;
    int totalRecords = 2;

    MembershipUserCollection coll = prov.FindUsersByName("testUser1", pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords);

    Assert.IsTrue(coll.Count == 2);

    List<string> usernames = new List<string>();

    foreach (MembershipUser user in coll)
    {
        usernames.Add(user.UserName);
    }

    Assert.AreNotEqual(usernames, null);
    Assert.IsTrue(usernames.Contains("testUser"));

    //Deletes Users
    prov.DeleteUser("testUser1", true);
    prov.DeleteUser("testUser2", true);

    //Tries to get users again
    user1 = prov.GetUser("testUser1", false);
    user2 = prov.GetUser("testUser2", false);

    //test that no users are returned
    Assert.AreEqual(null, user1);
    Assert.AreEqual(null, user2);

    }
```

Comment: You're finding users by name "testUser1" then don't understand why counting the returned users is one rather than 2? Am I misreading that?

Comment: You also have an extraneous test here: `Assert.AreNotEqual(usernames, null);` You *just* created that list a few lines above. You do not need to test that code. It will help with the readability.

Comment: I want to search for testUser. and any user with "testUser" contained in their username (testUser1, testUser2, testUser3, ect) should show in the list

Comment: But you have `prov.FindUsersByName("testUser1"...` and then expect it to contain "testUser2". I would also add that your test method name is misleading. You are doing much more than testing that one method. You should probably look at renaming the method or, better yet, breaking it out into multiple tests. It will be easier to debug that way, too.

Comment: Correct, but even when I have prov.FindUsersByName("testUser".... I still have my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. prov.FindUsersByName("testUser1"... - shoud be "testUser"?
2. usernames.ToArray() == string[] {"testUser1", "testUser2"} - it doesn't contain "testUser"

Comment: anyway Assert.AreNotEqual(usernames, null) better lookes like Assert.IsNotNull(usernames) and Assert.IsTrue(coll.Count == 2) like Assert.AreEqual(2, coll.Count) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1:
 You are looking for "testUser1" in a collection of two users. You get 1 and not 2 because there is only one user named "testUser1"

Issue 2:
  You are searching for "testUser" and not a partial.